# Ajax not posting to MYSQL or displaying success/error message upon submit

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form with one single select box that needs to be inputted into the database when submit button is clicked.

**Problems I am having:**

How do I make it automatically update without refreshing the page. So, if a selection was added in the database, it would automatically show in the select options?

**updated code**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$('#submitbut').click(function(e){

        var updateid = $("#updateid").val();

            if(updateid.length == 0){
            $("#success").text("make a selection.");
            $("updateid").focus();
        }
    else{

        var dataString = 'updateid='+ updateid

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'test.php',
            data: {updateid:dataString}
        }).done(function(){
            $('#success').text('success!');
        });
    }
        e.preventDefault();
        });    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your page was submitting was because you had some syntax errors. I will answer your points in random order.

To fix your validation problem, you should check to see if there is a value. Instead of checking for a value, you checked for a text node.

You used

```
if(updateid == "--")
```

But the `<option>` tag's value was empty. You should use this instead:

```
if(updateid.length == 0)
```

For AJAX, I like to use the `done()` function. I simplified your code for demonstration purposes, but it looks like this:

```
$.ajax().done(function(){
    $('#success').text('success!');
});
```

You also had 2 return false statements that weren't helping you. The proper way to prevent the form from submitting is preventDefault(), which you did have below, but due to your errors, it wasn't being called.

Another thing that will help is to use `<input type="button">`. This way, the form will never submit.

[Here is a demo of your code with working validation and AJAX](http://jsfiddle.net/a8jfdxg5/2/)

Comment: text/javascrip, text/html, showing all the right files

Comment: Have the window open while you do an AJAX request. The PHP file should appear. Click on it and it should show you the output

Comment: "request has no preview available"

Answer (score 0):

1. js does not disable default behavior of forms. You have to remove the type="submit" from your submit button.

Maybe use `$('#submitbut').attr('type', '');`

2. disable the button by default and check on change of the select box

   $('#selectbox').onChange(function() {
     if($(this).val() != '')
      $('#submitbut').removeAttr("disabled","disabled");
     else
      $('#submitbut').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
3. Make ajax calls to a getoptions.php where you retrieve all options from db and compare them to the options in the select.